# RyuJIT C# wrong sum result with /optimize

Tags: c#, sum, ryujit

I've this piece of code:

```
private void AnswerToCe(int currentBlock, int totalBlock = 0)
{
    byte[] bufferToSend;
    byte[] macDst = mac;
    byte[] macSrc = ConnectionManager.SInstance.GetMyMAC();
    byte[] ethType;
    byte[] header;

    if (Function == FlashFunction.UPLOAD_APPL || Function == FlashFunction.UPLOAD_BITSTREAM)
    {
        ethType = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)EthType.ETH_TYPE_UPLOAD);
        ethType = new byte[] { ethType[1], ethType[0] };
        header = Header.GetBytes((ushort)binaryBlocks.Count, (ushort)(currentBlock + 1), (ushort)binaryBlocks[currentBlock].Length);
        int index = 0;
        bufferToSend = new byte[macDst.Length + macSrc.Length + ethType.Length + header.Length + binaryBlocks[currentBlock].Length];
        Array.Copy(macDst, 0, bufferToSend, index, macDst.Length);
        index += macDst.Length;
        Array.Copy(macSrc, 0, bufferToSend, index, macSrc.Length);
        index += macSrc.Length;
        Logger.SInstance.Write(index.ToString(), "test index pre");
        Array.Copy(ethType, 0, bufferToSend, index, ethType.Length);
        index += ethType.Length;
        Logger.SInstance.Write(index.ToString(), "test index post");
        Array.Copy(header, 0, bufferToSend, index, header.Length);
        index += header.Length;
        Array.Copy(binaryBlocks[currentBlock], 0, bufferToSend, index, binaryBlocks[currentBlock].Length);
    }
```

If I build my application in Debug mode everything is ok, `test index pre` prints 12 and `test index post` prints 14. the same in Release mode with `Optimize code` unchecked. if i test with `Optimize code` checked `test index post` prints 18 instead of 14.
Same result if I replace `index += ethType.Length;` with `index += 2;`. seems only `index++;index++;` is working.
I tried this code in an empty application and sums are ok.
App is multithreading but there isn't no concurrency here.
Decompiled code from DLL seems ok.
Any ideas why this happen?

EDIT:
Happens only when app is compiled for x64. x86 is ok.
EDIT 3: some info of the build env:
visual studio 15.0.0-RTW+26228.4
framework 4.7.02053
can trigger this issue on framework 4.6.2 and 4.7. other frameworks aren't tested.
EDIT 5: [new, smaller example project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By7oA_lL6epnMVZrRUV5SUpPVkE). no dependencies needed.
EDIT 6: disassembly of the test project [here](https://pastebin.com/PvSmHkBQ). (too long to post it here)

Comment: "App is multithreading but there isn't no concurrency here." hard to say as this is only part of your code and it uses some variables from outside of this function.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx

Comment: @PawełŁukasik breakpoints are hit only once. index variable is not external.

Comment: @StefanE no floating point here

Comment: @rmbq I think you have to narrow the problem even more. Can you provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @vasek sure, i'll try to make one

Comment: @rmbq os in release mode only the `"test index post" is wrong? pre is ok?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik yes, pre is ok.

Comment: _"Happens only when app is compiled for x64"_ This wouldn't be [the](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/28/ryujit-bug-advisory-in-the-net-framework-4-6/) first [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570521/ryujit-producing-incorrect-results) within RyuJIT... first thing I'd check is that your .NET installation is fully up to date.

Comment: @JamesThorpe added info on build env. i think i'm quite up to date

Comment: Does it work correctly if you tell it to [use the old 64 bit jit compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/uselegacyjit-element)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe `useLegacyJit` seems to help!

Comment: Add `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` call then run in release mode outside visual studio.  When the breakpoint is hit, attach from visual studio and show the disassembly of the actual machine code that the JIT generated.

Comment: If it's looking like it might be a bug, and you've managed to reduce your problem to as small a project as possible, you might want to consider [searching for/raising a bug here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues).

Comment: it's already fixed here https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/11574 will be avaiable soon in a hotfix

Comment: @rmbq Now you've confirmed that, you can [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question with those details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an already reported bug in RyuJIT, more details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/11574). Will be fixed in an hotfix soon.